# How to control access to a Panel or View in Drupal based on CiviCRM Activity or completion of webform

Tags: cms-integration

I would like to control access to audio from a recent conference based on completion of a feedback form (webform).

I have created an Activity type for the feedback and added that completed activity to the contact upon completion of the form.

I would like to allow access to the audio content for those contacts with that completed activity, but can't see any Civi fields to operate on in Views (Filters, Contextual Filters, or Relationships) or in Panels (Selection Rules).

I'd prefer to use the selection rules in panels to do this, but will go with whatever works first!

I'm sure I've filtered on Civi stuff before in Views and I know everyone else does.  Not sure what's going on.

I've moved the database to a new server recently and tacked it onto the back of a different Drupal installation, but I've addded the requisite lines to settings.php and the other Civi integration modules work, e.g. Rules.  CiviCRM is working fine and I can integrate with Webform.

I'm using Drupal 7.43 and CiviCRM 4.7.6.

Thanks,
Lewis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd handle this by adding folks to a smart group with the selection criteria being those who have the activity associated with the completed webform.  Then use Group-Role synchronization to add folks to a role, and restrict access based on role.